# Google App Engine Versioning in the Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Google App Engine has the concept of app versions. i.e., you can have multiple versions of your app running concurrently and accessible at different subdomains. For instance: `http://1.my-app-name.appspot.com`, `http://2.my-app-name.appspot.com`.

What aspects of the app are actually "versioned" by this? Is it only the Python + Static files codebase? Does the datastore have the concept of "versions"? If not, then what happens when I update the definition of a Google App Engine model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Correct, app version refers only to your uploaded files. Both versions use with the same datastore.

Note that the datastore itself is schema-less. Each entity is an independent collection of key/value pairs. Two entities of the same kind don't have to share the same set of properties, or property types. db.Model provides an ORM abstraction around the datastore, but doesn't define or enforce any kind of global schema.

While the datstore isn't versioned, it does support [namespacing](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy.html). If you want a new datastore segment for each major version of your app, you can do this:

```
import os
from google.appengine.api import namespace_manager

namespace_manager.set_namespace(os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'])
```

Comment: Should probably split the version string and create the namespace based on the major version value. `major_ver, minor_ver = os.environ.get('CURRENT_VERSION_ID').rsplit('.', 1); namespace_manager.set_namespace(major_ver)` The minor version value changes with each deployment, even if you don't change the major version value.

Comment: Good call, for some reason I was thinking it returned major version only.

Comment: That's a good example when I was looking for an introduction with concrete example how to use namespaces so I won't have to use GQL IN and that in turn will enable me to use cursors for larger and more efficient pagination, should this plan work.

Comment: Good answer, but remember that the same datastore-indexes are applied for all entities in all namespaces.

Comment: Would you say segmenting the datastore with namespaces to support multiple instance versions that each have ""their own datastare""" would be a good approach?

Answer (score 7):

Datastore has no concept of versions.

When you update a model definition, any entities you create in the future will be of the new type, and the old ones will be of the old type.  This frequently leads to runtime errors if your code is not aware of these changes.

Comment: Also, indexes will (eventually) reflect the most recently uploaded index.yaml